# how to fill a plot only in an interval

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to produce a plot wth a fill *only in an interval*
I can set one boundary to the interval, but using 2 gives an error message:

This piece of code works

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 500)
y = np.sin(4 * np.pi * x) * np.exp(-5 * x)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.fill_between(x,0, y,where=x>0.25)
plt.show()
```

[Obtained figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90qyR.png)

Tis piece of code gives an error

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 500)
y = np.sin(4 * np.pi * x) * np.exp(-5 * x)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.fill_between(x,0, y,where=0.5>x>0.25)
plt.show()
```

----> 7 plt.fill_between(x,0, y,where=0.5>x>0.25)
      8 plt.show()

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

I could not figure out how to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Boolean "and":

```
plt.fill_between(x,0, y,where=(0.5>x) & (x>0.25))
```

Comment: Great that works. I still need to figure out why this "where" statement works in plt.fill_between and not in plt.plot. Any idea?